# How to check rows and columns for matching elements

Tags: c

The dimensions m and n (1 <= m, n <= 100) of the matrix A are entered by the keyboard, and then the elements of the matrix. The matrix contains only 1 or 0 as its own elements. Write a program that will print how many pairs of indexes (i, j) there are that only consist of ones in the i-row and j-column and print all the pairs (i, j) for which the requearements met. When printing, the indexes i and j start at 0.

Example:

Input:

4 3

1 1 1 1

1 0 1 1

1 0 1 1

Output:

(0, 0)

(2, 0)

(3, 0)

Comment: Please consider adding what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: If your pairs are (i,j) where I represents a row index and j represents a column index, the pairs in your output appear to be reversed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing what you got so far, and where you are stuck.